# Why am I missing a row in my weight matrix during back propagation?

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I added the code below up to the point of where I get the error.

```
    clear; close; clc;

    lambda = 1;

    in= 3;
    h1 = 9;
    h2 = 6;
    h3 = 4;
    h4 = 1;
    m = 50;

% We generate some 'random' test data

    Theta1 = rand(9,4);
    Theta2 = rand(6,10);
    Theta3 = rand(4,7);
    Theta4 = rand(1, 5);

% generate X
    
    X  = rand(m, in);
    y  = 1 + mod(1:m,  h4)';

% Setup some useful variables

    m = size(X, 1);
    J = 0;
    Theta1_grad = zeros(size(Theta1));
    Theta2_grad = zeros(size(Theta2));
    Theta3_grad = zeros(size(Theta3));
    Theta4_grad = zeros(size(Theta4));

% forward propagation


    a1 = [ones(size(X,1),1) X];
    z2 = a1 * Theta1';
    a2 = [ones(size(z2), 1) 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z2))];
    z3 = a2 * Theta2';
    a3 = [ones(size(z3), 1) 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z3))];
    z4 = a3 * Theta3';
    a4 = [ones(size(z4), 1) 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z4))];
    z5 = a4 * Theta4';
    a5 = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z5));

    J = 1/m * sum(sum((-y.*log(a5)-(1-y).*log(1-a5))));

    J = J + (lambda/(2*m)*(sum(sum(Theta1(:, 2:end).^2))+sum(sum(Theta2(:, 2:end).^2)) ...
           +sum(sum(Theta3(:, 2:end).^2))+sum(sum(Theta4(:, 2:end).^2))));

% back propagation

    d5 = (a5 .- y);  
    d4 = (d5 * Theta4).*1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-a4)).*(1-1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-a4)));
    d3 = (d4 * Theta3).*1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-a3)).*(1-1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-a3)));
```

Comment: Please provide/describe the error you receive.

Comment: >> d3 = (d4 * Theta3).*1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-a3)).*(1-1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-a3)));
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 50x5, op2 is 4x7)

Comment: The size of `d4` is 50x5. You've defined `Theta3` to be 4x7. I'm not sure what result you expected. The inner dimensions of matrix multiplication must agree, so if you change to `Theta3 = rand(5,7);`, your code will not raise an error, but since this is random test data, I can't tell if that's the correct thing to do.

Comment: If I change Theta3 = rand(5,7); I get an error in the forward propagation.

Comment: a4 = [ones(size(z4), 1) 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z4))];
>>     z5 = a4 * Theta4';
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 50x6, op2 is 5x1)

Comment: I assume you are intending to do matrix multiplication at those steps. in that case your multiplication must be [m x n] x [n x p].  I assume there is some meaning associated with all of these inputs. random missized test data is just not going to work.

Comment: I realize that it is not going to work, but the matrix math should work out. I am trying to figure out why I am getting a missed matched matrix on the back propagation. The data in the matrices is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: I got it working.